# Правильно вытянуть ответ из Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Я хочю через *Ajax* взять контент и вставить на текущую страницу.

вот фрагмент кода:

```
<div class="select-wrapp">
  <!-- onchange="with (this) alert (options [selectedIndex].value + options [selectedIndex].text) -->
    <select class="zh-select-style js-select-delivery js-content-delivery-ajax" name="payment">
        {|foreach from=$deliveryArray item="d"|}
            <option value="{|$d.id|}">{|$d.name|} ({|$d.price|number_format:2|} {|$currency|})</option>
        {|/foreach|}
    </select>
    <!-- style="display: none" -->
    <input type="text" name="id" value="" id="js-select-delivery-input" >
    <input class="js-required" id="js-delivery" data-error="Выберите способ доставки" type="hidden" name="delivery" value="{|$deliveryDefault|}">
</div>
```

```js
$j(function () {
    $j('.js-content-delivery-ajax').change(function () {
    $j('#js-select-delivery-input').val($j(this).val());
    var id_select = $j(this).val();
       $j.ajax({
           url: "/ajax/content/delivery/",
           dataType: "json",
           data:{
               id: id_select
           },
           success: function(data) {
              console.log('hello');
              // $j('.js-content-delivery-block').html('<p>hello from delivery</p>');
           }
       });
   });
});
```

И в зависимости от выбраного поставщика в форме заказа (ниже) должны добавиться необходимые поля, которые генерируются по другому запрашиваемому URL в зависимости от переданного id.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все вроде ничего, но пришедший ответ никак не могу вставить в свой *html*, в разделе *success* даже `console.log('hello');` не отрабатывает.

Как мне достучатся к нужному контенту, который пришел в ответе?

Comment: Раз `console.log` не отрабатывает - значит, функция в `success` вообще не вызывается. Вы пробовали добавлять `error` и проверять, какая ошибка возвращается?

Comment: не вижу запросов на `/ajax/content/delivery/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А у вас сервер вообще JSON возвращает? Из предложенного скрина видно, что в ответе результат работы `var_dump($some_array)`, a не JSON.

Возможно где-то в php коде есть и вывод var_dump для отладки, и отправка JSON, тогда понятно, и вывод var_dump и json уходит на клиент и тот не понимает ответ от сервера т.к. ждет таки JSON (dataType: "json")

Comment: Кстати может быть, ща проверю

Answer (score 1):

Рабочий пример на jQuery (Дополнительно добавил div для вывода).

HTML:

```
<div class="select-wrapp">
  <!-- onchange="with (this) alert (options [selectedIndex].value + options [selectedIndex].text) -->
    <select class="zh-select-style js-select-delivery js-content-delivery-ajax" name="payment">
           <option value="1">Опция 1</option>
           <option value="2">Опция 2</option>
    </select>
    <!-- style="display: none" -->
    <input type="text" name="id" value="" id="js-select-delivery-input" >
    <input class="js-required" id="js-delivery" data-error="Выберите способ доставки" type="hidden" name="delivery" value="{|$deliveryDefault|}">
    <div class="js-content-delivery-block"></div>    
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.js-content-delivery-ajax').on('change', function () {
    $('#js-select-delivery-input').val($(this).val());
    var id_select = $(this).val();
       $.ajax({
           url: "/echo/json/",
           dataType: "json",
           data:{
               id: id_select
           },
           success: function(data) {
              $('.js-content-delivery-block').html('<p>hello from delivery</p>');
           }
       });
});
```

Рабочее демо: https://jsfiddle.net/qk85qno3/3/ Здесь обращение ajax идет к заглушке jsfiddle. Если этот код не будет работать у Вас - копайте в сторону отвечающей стороны.

Comment: $j — по-моему используется noconflict

Comment: Я протупил, видимо у автора просто где-то выше по коду есть что-то типа `$j = jQuery.noConflict();` или `$j = jQuery;` Но сути это не меняет, пример рабочий.

Answer (score -1):

Судя по всему html код генерируется в каком то шаблоне. Проще всего будет создать новый php файл который будет отвечать за логику данного selecta. И делать запрос к нему напрямую.
К примеру select.php

```
<?php
echo '<div class="select-wrapp">
    <select class="zh-select-style js-select-delivery js-content-delivery-ajax" name="payment">
        <option value="'. $_REQUEST['id'] .'">test</option>
    </select>
    <!-- style="display: none" -->
    <input type="text" name="id" value="" id="js-select-delivery-input" >
    <input class="js-required" id="js-delivery" data-error="Выберите способ доставки" type="hidden" name="delivery" value="">
</div>';
?>
```

JS код

```
$j(function () {
$j('.js-content-delivery-ajax').change(function () {
    $j('#js-select-delivery-input').val($j(this).val());
    var id_select = $j(this).val();
    $j.ajax({
        url: "/select.php",
        dataType: "html",
        data:{
            id: id_select
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $j('.js-content-delivery-block').html('<p>hello from delivery</p>');
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Очень плохой подход к созданию решений на PHP...

Comment: Боюсь создание решений на PHP - очень плохой подход.

Comment: Ок, перефразирую - плохой подход - "не знаю как работает - изменю логику и буду использовать"...